# Em PHP comparar 2 variáveis ignorando Maiúsculo e acentos

Tags: php

Em PHP tenho duas variáveis:

```
$var1 = "Sem danos visíveis";
$var2 = "sem danos visiveis";
```

Preciso comparar elas duas e saber se são iguais, se fizer como abaixo, claro, vai dizer que não são iguais devido ao primeiro caratrer da `$var1` ser maísucula e não ter acento na `$var2`:

```
if($var1 == $var2){
   echo "são iguais";
}else{
   echo "não são iguais";
}
```

Mas nesse exemplo acima precisaria de uma resposta "são iguais", ignorando os acentos/carateres especiais/maísucla/minuscula.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php as soluções que as pessoas costumam usar são erradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pesquisei sobre e não achei uma forma nativa de fazer isso sem ignorar a acentuação, mas no entanto encontrei essa função:

```php
function stripaccents(string $input): string {
    return strtr($input, 'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ', 'aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
}
```

Logo, você pode utilizar essa função para ver se duas strings são idênticas, ignorando a acentuação e também a caixa alta.

```php
function strcompare(string $a, string $b): bool {
    return strcasecmp(stripaccents($a), stripaccents($b)) == 0;
}
```